# Populate a String[] in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

Cant seem to find an answer to this for whatever reason. I made a column in my Parse data browser for an array, but am not sure how to save Strings to it in code. Both `user.add("myArray", "a String");` and `user.put("myArray", "a String");` dont seem to work. Hows this done?

Using `user.put("key", myArray)` throws:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for value: class [Ljava.lang.String;
>   at com.parse.ParseObject.performPut(ParseObject.java:2922)

Even though the column with that specified key is labeled for an Array.

Using `user.add()` throws no error and has no effect.

Comment: Read the documentation please https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-arrays

Comment: @MoNazemi Are you serious? Ofc I read the docs. That example in your link does not work.

Comment: Please give more details, post your code and explain the errors you are getting. Surely people cannot help without sufficient details of the problem

Comment: @MoNazemi I updated the post with a tad more detail, though its probably irrelevant as my question is really just how to do it in the first place, as I havent found it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String [] test= {"hello", "world"};
user.put("myArray", Arrays.asList(test));
user.saveInBackground();
```